# navigating to new page in jquery touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, href, jqtouch

I am trying to navigate to a new `div/page` based off of a `JavaScript` condition. Normally I would just add an a tag with the `href` `"#thispage"` using `jQuery touch`, but it's based off of a `dropdown` menu, so what I want to do is something like `window.location.href = "#thispage"` but it doesn't really work the same my `"#home"` still has `class` `"current"`. I can remove the `class` from `"#home"` and add it to `"#thispage"`, but this messes up any further `navigation` with `jq touch`. So `jq touch` has a `goTo` `function` that passes in the `topage`, animation, and reverse is there any way to access it from my `javascript?` I'm stuck.

```
function getpage()
{
    var id = document.getElementsByName('id')[0].value;
    if (id == 1)
    {
        //window.location.href="#thispage";
        //$(goTo('#thispage','slideleft'));
    }
    else
    {
        //window.location.href="#thatpage";
        //$(goTo('#thatpage','slideleft'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about JQTouch but for navigation you may try this `jQT.goTo('#pageLink', 'dissolve'); //`

Comment: No, it tells me that jQT is not defined

Comment: `jQT.goTo(Page, Animation);` basic is this, but i think in your script file `$` sign is defined for `JQT` so maybe this works `$(goTo('#pageLink', 'dissolve'));`